# Haskell - Defining multiple helper functions in where statements

Tags: haskell

I was thinking of putting helper functions that are only accessed by one function into a `where` statement. It would look something like this.

```hs
f :: Int -> Int
f a = g a + 1
  where
    g :: Int -> Int
    g a = 2 * a
```

(This example is just to illustrate the idea.)

To me the benefit of that would be that these helper functions can access all the arguments of the top-level function and that it is clear what purpose the helper functions serve.

Are there any problems or drawbacks with this approach?

Comment: I would suggest being careful with your variable names, though. Here `a` is the name of two separate variables which happen to have the same value. If you want `g` to be able to access `f`'s version of `a`, you should not give `g` an argument with the same name.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @bradrn that this is common and idiomatic usage and you should not hesitate to use it.  However there are some gotchas that you should know about.

When the type is polymorphic, you can run into issues with type variable scope.

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
f x = g x
    where
    g :: a -> a
    g y = x + y
```

This will, surprisingly, result in a type error.  If you remove `g`'s type signature it will work fine.  That is because the `a` in `g`'s type signature is a *different* `a` than the one in `f`'s, so Haskell expects that `g :: a -> a` should hold no matter what `a` is, regardless of `f`'s signature.  The workaround is either to remove the signature, or use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension to explicitly scope the outer type variable, using the following (imo un-intuitive) syntax:

```
f :: forall a. Num a => a -> a
f x = g x
    where
    g :: a -> a  -- a now refers to the same as as in f's signature
    g y = x + y
```

The other issue has already been pointed out by @amalloy in a comment, that the helper function can re-bind names that the outer function already bound. For example:

```
f x y = g y x
   where
   g x y = x ++ y
```

Calling `f "foo" "bar"` will result in `"barfoo"` because `g` has rebound the variables `x` and `y`.

The final gotcha is that it's kind of awkward when mixing with `do` notation.  The following is a common pattern I come across:

```
main = do
    [n, s] <- getArgs
    go (read n)
  where
    go 0 = pure ()
    go n = do
        putStrLn $ show n ++ s
        go (n-1)
```

In hopes that I could call `./Main 99 ' bottles of beer on the wall'`.  Sadly, the scope of `s` does not extend into the `where` block, and we are forced to either make `s` an extra argument of `go` (which, in ugly real-world code, can lead to `go` having quite a few arguments), or to use `let` inside the `do` block instead:

```
main = do
    [n, s] <- getArgs
    let go 0 = pure ()
        go n = do
            putStrLn $ show n ++ s
            go (n-1)
    go (read n)
```

But, despite its few gotchas, using `where` blocks for a helper function that has access to some of the wrapping functions arguments is 100% Kosher.

Answer (score 2):

There are no drawbacks whatsoever to this approach — it is incredibly common, and precisely what `where` blocks were designed for.

**EDIT:** See @luqui’s answer for a more detailed overview of some common ‘gotchas’ you need to watch out for when using functions in `where` blocks.

Comment: How about nested function definitions in where statements? Like, you define g as a helper for f and h as a helper for g.

Comment: @TippFehler Sometimes that's just the ticket, though empirically I find it rare in the code I write. I consider it a code smell -- something to wrinkle your nose and double-check for rottenness, with the occasional outcome of having found an excellent cheese instead of rot.